# On duplicate key update: existing value plus new value

Tags: mysql

Is there a possibility to use a value from a column which shouldn't be updated for updating the value of another column? For example, something like this:

Table: `product_id, color_id, amount, received`

Query:

```
INSERT INTO orders (product_id, color_id, amount)
VALUES (100, 101, 5),(100,102,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    product_id=values(product_id),
    color_id=values(color_id),
    amount=received+values(amount)
```

So, if there isn't an existing key a row will inserted with the amount value, but if there is a unique key the amount value is the value of the column received plus the amount value from the query.

Comment: what you've got should work. but why are you updating the product_id/color_id fields? If they're the unique key that caused the `on dupe`, then you already KNOW that the values are the same, so there's no point in forcing the db to update a field to be the exact same value it already is.

Comment: Does this not work?  It works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03a21/1

Comment: Marc B, that is correct, I made a copy/paste fault. Rocket Hazmat, the one you submitted is also updating the column `received`. That isn't correct since this value is unknown at the moment the query is executed.

Comment: The `received` isn't being updated in my example.

Comment: You are completely right!! Thanks!